# The Problem in Google Sign-In for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**Choose Project From The List.**

[image]

**Assign Product Name Here**

[image]

**Finally I Got This Error**

[image]

When i am trying to integrate google sign-in in android application then i am getting above mentioned problem.

Comment: Try to give name other than Google, you can't just give project name Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google **won't accept any apps starting with Google**. Try giving some other name.

Answer (score 0):

Define different names for your project.